# How to print out selected text in UITextview?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uitextview

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text
{
    NSLog (@"This is selected text in UITextView %@", selectedText);
}
```

How to print out the selected text in `UITextView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:[textView selectedRange]];
NSLog (@"This is selected text in UITextView %@", selectedText);
```

Comment: How can I do in with live UItextview, when user changed selected Text?

- (void)textViewDidChangeSelection:(UITextView *)textView
{
    
    NSString *selectedText = [textView.text substringWithRange:[textView selectedRange]];

    NSLog (@"This is selected text in UITextView %@", selectedText);

    //This method is called when a selection of text is made or changed
}

Answer (score 1):

Create an outlet for UITextView, say `yourTextViewName`.

(Make sure it is connected, just in case you are not using dragging feature.)

Then in any of the method use this statement.

```
_yourTextViewName.text = [_yourTextViewName.text substringWithRange:[_yourTextViewName selectedRange]];
```

Comment: After posting this answer, I read your comment in Daniel's answer. Please explain me what you exactly want to do? As in my example.. do you want to update `@"some text"` automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but I want to add more clarity. I have created several dynamic UITextViews and would like to be able to simply detect which one the user clicked on.

**Add this to the UITextView:**

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTapRecognized:)];
singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[textView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

**What I used differently:**

```
UITextView *selectedTextView = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
```

**Add this to your ViewController to recognize user taps:**

```
- (void)tapRecognized:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
{
    UITextView *selectedTextView = (UITextView *)gestureRecognizer.view;
    NSLog (@"UITextView test:%@", selectedTextView.text);
}
```